# How to use await in a parallel foreach?

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, parallel.foreach, pim

So I spent the better part of the night trying to figure this out.

I was fortunate to get introduced to  `Parallel.ForEach` yesterday and it works like I want it to do except from one detail.

I have the following:

```csharp
Parallel.ForEach(data, (d) =>
{
    try
    {
        MyMethod(d, measurements);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log
    }
});
```

Within the method "MyMethod" I have a lot of logic that gets done and most of it is fine but I make API calls where I fetch data and I use an `async` task for this to be able to use `await` in order for the code to wait until that specific part gets executed and then move on:

```csharp
private async void MyMethod(PimData pimData, IEnumerable<ProductMeasurements> measurements)
{
    try
    {
        // a lot of logic but most relevant part 

        await Task.WhenAll(ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic(pimData.ProductNumber, entity));

        await Task.WhenAll(resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles(pimData.ProductType + pimData.ProductSize,SwepImageType.Png, ResourceFileTypes.ThreeD, entity, LinkTypeId.ProductResource));

        await Task.WhenAll(resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles(pimData.ProductSketch, SwepImageType.Png, ResourceFileTypes.Sketch, entity, LinkTypeId.ProductResource));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log
    }
}
```

> **Problems**:
>
> 1 For starters the loop finishes before all code is finished
>
> 2 Second problem is that I get "Task was cancelled" in a lot of API calls
>
> 3 And third as mentioned above, the code does not wait for each method to fully execute.

I cant get it to execute everything in `ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic()` method
before moving forward to the next step.

This gives me the following issues (more issues):

In this method I create an item and add it to the db, and this item needs more info that I get from an API call that is done inside of `ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic()` but the problem is that several items get created and have to wait for the rest of the data which is not what I desire.

*SIDE-NOTE: I am aware that creating an item and adding to the db before all data is there is not best practice but I am integrating toward PIM and the process for that is delicate*

I want several threads running but at the same time I want the full logic to execute for each item before moving on to the next method.

Clarification:

Several items running

Each item handles **ALL** the logic it needs to handle before moving on to the next part of the code. Normally do this with `await`.

In the code above `resourceImportManager()` method gets executed before `ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic()` is finished, which is what I don't want.

Instead of a `Parallel.ForEach` I used :

```csharp
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(data, measurements));
Task.WaitAll(task1);
```

But that wasn't much of a help.

Fairly new to this and haven't been able to understand where I am doing it wrong.

EDIT:
Updated the problems with this

EDIT: this is how `ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic()` looks:

```csharp
public async Task ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic(string productNumber, Entity entity)
{
    try
    {
        GrafGeneratorManager grafManager = new GrafGeneratorManager();
        var graphMeasurmentList = await MeasurmentHandler.GetMeasurments(productNumber);

        if (graphMeasurmentList.Count == 0) return;

        var chart = await grafManager.GenerateChart(500, 950, SystemColors.Window, ChartColorPalette.EarthTones,
                    "legend", graphMeasurmentList);

        await AddChartsAndAddToXpc(chart, entity, productNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Background to this:
I make a call to an API to get a lot of data. For each item in this data I need to make an API call and get data that I apply to the item.

After reading comments which also got me thinking in a different way. I can perhaps loop through all my items and do minor logic for them and add a URL in a task list and make a separate task that executes this one by one.

Will keep this updated

Comment: Use callback delegates once the processing complete.

Comment: Any particular reason why `MyMethod` is an `async void` and not an `async Task`?

Comment: @GWigWam no particular reason, was meaning to change it, thanks for reminding me

Comment: What does `resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles` return. For a starter it looks like you are using WaitAll and WhenAll for single tasks. Also, async void is a big no no, you could probably change `Parallel.ForEach` to `Task.WhenAll` with some refactoring.

Comment: Also, parallel.for is better for CPU bound work, and Task.WhenAll for I/O bound work. using async/await in parellel for is a bit of a design flaw imho

Comment: @Peter Bons resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles doesn't return anything, I just want it to execute everything in there before moving on.

Comment: if it does not return anything, how can it be a parameter of Task.WhenAll ?

Comment: @Peter Bons:  public async Task HandleEntityImageFiles
was a void before I tried every possible thing I can think of to make it execute everything

Comment: To echo comments above, either it's **CPU-bound**, in which case you should use `Parallel.ForEach`, or it's **IO-bound**, in which case you should use async.

Comment: then you should use `await HandleEntityImageFiles` instead of await `await Task.WhenAll(HandleEntityImageFiles)` as it returns a single Task. Now, you can run multiple tasks concurrent but then I would expect something like `await Task.WhenAll(ExecuteMeasurmentAndChartLogic(pimData.ProductNumber, entity), resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles(xxx), resourceImportManager.HandleEntityImageFiles(yyy);`

Comment: But I suggest you read some more tutorials before creating such logic as you are mixing up too many things and this is not te best place to explain all these things.

Comment: @Peter Bons I did use await before using Task.WhenAll, gave me the same result. As for more reading, I agree and I have but I need to make an optimization and I am trying to learn as I go.

Comment: Consider TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @Peter Bons could you share a thought on my solution below.Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `Parralel.ForEach` at all. Make your method to return Task instead of void, collect all the task and wait them like:

```
Task.WaitAll(data.Select(d => MyMethod(d, someParam)).ToArray());
```

Comment: This does give me a better result thus far but I am concerned, does it actually execute the logic for each item simultaneously? Seems to go alot slower than the loop I started with

Comment: The way I see this is that each item gets a task but item two waits for item one to execute, that is not what I want, gets me back to a normal foreach loop

Comment: The code that I provided is Asynchronous and Parallel. It might be executed in one thread if Thread pool configuration is broken or there're insufficient threads to capture. Or maybe MyMethod has bottleneck and actually access the same blocking resource. However if this method is valid, then my answer should be valid as well.

Comment: There is not blocking resourse. I am debuging this and after a few items it stops and waits for items to execute. This is to slow

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Then your actual method isn't designed to run in parallel, and you need to fix *that*.

Comment: @Servy I think I did, Check my answer below.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN That answer *reduces* the amount of work that can be done in parallel, for the main work being done, and *incorrectly* parallelizes work that can't be done in parallel, resulting in unsafe code.

Comment: Finaly decided to accept this answer since it answers the question asked. However I will not use the solution since I need multithreading and this locks each thread.

Comment: How about `Task.WaitAll(data.Select(d => Task.Run(() => MyMethod(d, someParam)).ToArray()));` to retain parallelism? Haven't tested myself, but just an idea.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind is that WaitAll does not give you a way to stop before everything runs. In a normal Parallell.ForEach, you can loopState.Stop() and exit early if you run into a fatal case. That can be really nice when handling many operations.

Comment: You can use Parallel.ForEachAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0